# Why GL_SPECULAR doesn't work?

Tags: opengl

I've downloaded the code from NeHe tutorial, the one about lighting. The original code didn't include  the specular light, I simply added it. I defined a free color-lighting arrays and shut out the other lights.

```
GLfloat LightBlack[] = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f };
GLfloat LightGreen[] = { 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f };

...

glLightfv(GL_LIGHT1, GL_AMBIENT, LightBlack);       // add lighting. (ambient)
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT1, GL_SPECULAR, LightGreen);      // THIS IS WHAT I ADDED
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT1, GL_DIFFUSE, LightBlack);       // add lighting. (diffuse).
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT1, GL_POSITION, LightPosition);   // set light position.

...

glutSolidTeapot(0.8f);
```

However, the result seemed that all the lights are shut, there are no lights at all. Seems that the GL_SPECULAR didn't work. Why is that?

With glDisable(GL_LIGHTING);
[image: With glDisable(GL_LIGHTING);]

With glDisable(GL_LIGHTING);
[image: With glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);]

Comment: Shouldn't the second pic be titled glEnable(...) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You also need to adjust the material's specular (which is multiplied by the light's specular) and shininess (which adjusts the hotspot's falloff) properties. The default for these are zeros. try this:

```
GLfloat white[] = { 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f };

glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_SPECULAR, white);
glMaterialf(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_SHININESS, 80.0f);
```

Comment: Yes, you are right! Except the second glMaterialfv should be glMaterialf because the last parameter is a value, not pointer.